# How can I determine how many months, weeks and days have elapsed between two dates?

Tags: informix

INFORMIX-SQL 7.32 (SE) Perform screen:

Let's say I have a start date of FEB-15-2010 and an end date of MAY-27-2010. I can calculate the number of elapsed days with 'let elapsed_days = end_date - start_date', but how can I convert these number of days into 3 months, 1 week and 5 days?

A raw calculation I've seen used, rounding every month to 31 days, since if you take the number of days in each month, add them up and divide them by 12 gives you 30.5 days average
per month, then taking elapsed days and dividing it by 31 produces 3.31 months, but this method is unacceptable for my needs.

Comment: Determining weeks and days between the dates is basically trivial - there is a fully deterministic formula for doing that. As soon as you mention 'months' too, you wander off the straight-and-narrow path into the tangled undergrowth. You have to define (rigorously) what a month means, in all circumstances, remembering to account for leap days. Where it gets interesting is with combinations like 2010-02-28 and 2010-05-29, or 2012-02-29 and 2012-05-28 (29, 30, 21), etc. Since 'a month' is a variable quantity, we have to know what meaning you want to ascribe to 'month' to know what value to give.

Comment: FWIW: Oracle's MONTHS_BETWEEN() function gives interesting results for the pairs of dates cited - the values are: 3.03225806451613, 2.96774193548387, 3.0, 3.03225806451613, 3.0 respectively.  Note that the number of months between 30th May and 29th February is bigger than the number of months between 31st May and 29th February.  That is the definition of MONTHS_BETWEEN().  You have to know about this to use it.  Of course, Oracle's MONTHS_BETWEEN is not implemented in SE, only in IDS.  But the point stands - without the requisite definition of MONTH, no-one can produce the code for you.

Comment: @Jonathan- OK, do you remember the dates dimension lookup table my app uses (see posting: "Date lookup table 1990-01-01:2041-12-31")?.. Can you think of a method in which I could devise an algorithim which would accomplish my goal?.. or should I just use 30.5 days avg., rounding all months to 31 days to base YMWD calcs?.. it would be to all customers advantage that every month is based on 31 days, when some months actually have 28, 29 and 30 days because customers will get these days for free when calcking their interest amt's, (e.g. 16 to 31 days = 20% interest, 32 to 36 days = 25%..) ;-)

Comment: What do you want the months to represent?  That will control what you do.  Usually, it is rigged to pay the house - but that's because the house defines the terms.  I would avoid the term 'month' and use just weeks; that is unambiguous and calculable.  In parts of the bonds markets, every month has 28 days, I believe.  Working with a 30.5-day average month is not unreasonable.

Comment: @Jonathan- LOL, In Puerto Rico, or perhaps several other places in the world, pawnshop customers would start a riot if we were to base each month on 28 days, charging them an extra 5% interest between days 29 to 33! Mentality here and most everywhere is: if I pawned something on JAN-15, next int pymt is on FEB-15, pawned JAN-30, pymt FEB-28.. Pawned JAN-30, paid two months int on MAR-30. In other words, most people pay one months int pymts from one month to another, JAN->FEB, FEB->MAR .. so basing each month on 31 days preserves the peace, thus reason for my date fact table!

Answer (score 3):

This could probably stand some more rigorous testing, and there is certainly scope to tidy up the output (ie remove "0 months" substrings), but I think it gets you most of the way there...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE informix.datediff(d1 DATE, d2 DATE) RETURNING VARCHAR(255);
    DEFINE yrcount, mthcount, wkcount, daycount INTEGER;
    DEFINE dx DATE;

    LET mthcount = ((YEAR(d2) - YEAR(d1)) * 12) + MONTH(d2) - MONTH(d1);
    IF DAY(d1) <= DAY(d2) THEN
        LET daycount = DAY(d2) - DAY(d1);
    ELSE
        LET dx = MDY(MONTH(d1),1,YEAR(d1))+1 UNITS MONTH;
        LET daycount = dx - d1;     -- elapsed days from last month
        LET daycount = daycount + DAY(d2) - 1; -- elapsed days from this month
    END IF;

    LET yrcount = mthcount / 12;
    LET mthcount = MOD(mthcount,12);
    LET wkcount = daycount / 7;
    LET daycount = MOD(daycount,7);

    RETURN d1 || " - " || d2 || ": " || yrcount || " years, " || mthcount
         || " months, " || wkcount || " weeks and " || daycount || " days ";
END PROCEDURE;
```

ie:

```
execute procedure datediff(TODAY, "19/03/2011");
(expression)  21/06/2010 - 19/03/2011: 0 years, 9 months, 4 weeks and 0 days

execute procedure datediff(TODAY, "22/03/2011");
(expression)  21/06/2010 - 22/03/2011: 0 years, 9 months, 0 weeks and 1 days

execute procedure datediff("08/02/2010", "08/05/2011");
(expression)  08/02/2010 - 08/05/2011: 1 years, 3 months, 0 weeks and 0 days

execute procedure datediff("31/03/2010", TODAY);
(expression)  31/03/2010 - 21/06/2010: 0 years, 3 months, 3 weeks and 0 days

execute procedure datediff(TODAY-3, TODAY);
(expression)  18/06/2010 - 21/06/2010: 0 years, 0 months, 0 weeks and 3 days

execute procedure datediff(TODAY-33, TODAY);
(expression)  19/05/2010 - 21/06/2010: 0 years, 1 months, 0 weeks and 2 days
```

Comment: great for an SPL, but the feature needs to be accomplished within ISQL's Perform screen instructions section.

Comment: It is probably 15 years since I last played with ISQL, ACE and Perform, and I've never used SE. But would it be possible to link the Perform screen to a VIEW of your table that includes this as a virtual column?

Comment: Perhaps with IDS.. It's probably best to create and call a cfunc 'cymwd(start_date,end_date)' to return: centuries, years, months, weeks, days and pf_putval with ESQL/C.

Comment: VIEWS can be created in SE, however you cannot display more than one table within the same screen when declaring the viewed table in the tables section of the perform source code.

Comment: I could not find an example this good in the Informix docs. Thanks.

Comment: Entirely your business @FrankComputer, but I can't help wondering why after two years you'd suddenly untick this answer; especially when there aren't any others?

Comment: because there's a much easier way to do it than your example.

Comment: But you're going to keep it to yourself? Why not add it here for the benefit of everyone else?